# Laravel nested relation filter

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

Have a query, how I can filter results by translation relation (by name column)

```
$item = Cart::select('product_id','quantity')
->with(['product.translation:product_id,name','product.manufacturer:id,name'])
->where($cartWhere)
->get();
```

my model

```
Cart.php

    public  function product($language = null)
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Product','id','product_id');
    }

Product.php

    public  function translations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductTranslation','product_id','id'); 
    }
```

Update v1.0

do like this, but query takes too long time

```
            $item = Cart::select('product_id','quantity')
                ->with(['product.translation', 'product.manufacturer:id,name'])
                ->where($cartWhere)
                ->when($search,function ($q) use ($search) {
                    $q->whereHas('product.translation', function (Builder $query) use ($search) {
                        $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
                        $query->select('name');
                    });
                }
                )
                ->get() ;
```

Comment: Document will be help you : https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: @xNoJustice try try ```$item = Cart::select('product_id','quantity')
            ->with(['product' => function($product) use ($search) {
                $product->join('product_translations', 'products.id', '=', 'product_translations.product_id');
                $product->where( 'product_translations.name', 'LIKE','%'.$search.'%');
            }, 'product.manufacturer:id,name'])
           ->where($cartWhere)
           ->get();``` but this no work for me. don't know why but some times result received wrong like translation relation received not product_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the array within your with() method, you can pass a function as a value.

```
Cart::select('product_id','quantity')
    ->with([
         'product', function($query) {
              $query->where($filteringAndConditionsHere);
          }
    ]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading